# C++ ODB понимание db view object join type

Tags: c++, база-данных, join, inner-join

Не могу понять как работает join-type в ODB-view типах.

Если мне надо во вью получить из базы несколько объектов на основе таблицы `Poster`. При этом из таблицы `Poster` надо прочитать значение колонки `posterObject` и по нему прочитать весь объект типа `PosterObject` из одноименной таблицы `PosterObject`, то это записывается так и корректно работает:

```
#pragma db view object(Poster) \
    object(PosterObject inner) \
```

Мне надо добавить в это представление еще одно поле по принципу: взять из таблицы `Poster` (для каждой записи) значение колонки `user` и по нему прочитать объект `UserAccount` из одноименной таблицы. Я записываю это так:

```
#pragma db view object(Poster) \
    object(PosterObject inner) \
    object(UserAccount inner: Poster::m_user == UserAccount::m_rowid)
```

Это правильно?
И что будет если записать без inner? Объясните разницу пожалуйста.

```
object(UserAccount: Poster::m_user == UserAccount::m_rowid)
```